# Intercepting a successful response (possible callback) before RestKit saves it in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/mypath/objects" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    // Use objects that are returned.
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Handle error
}];
```

This method of RestKit will perform a request, mapping, saving to core data, and performing the success callback AFTER saving. What I want to know is the method I can use to get the response and perform a callback BEFORE RestKit automatically saves it in core data. I still want to be able to use the ability of RestKit to do the mapping and saving but I want to intercept or at least get a callback BEFORE it performs saving of data.

Comment: To do what? What's the end goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it by implementing the callback block of the RKManagedObjectRequestOperation before the mapping begins since this will be called after a successful HTTP response and before the automatic saving to core data:

```
[managedObjectRequestOperation setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:^id(id deserializedResponseBody) {

    //do something

    return deserializedResponseBody;
}];
```